# Add :after to :enabled CSS pseudo-class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to add an `:after` pseudo element to `:enabled` pseudo-class of certain types/classes only in pure CSS?

As a sample, based on your feed-backs, I wish to have no border around the disabled radio (forgive me for not centering the `:after` elements): https://jsfiddle.net/msdobrescu/z398jjoj/20/

Comment: If you could show us what you want to do we might be able to provide a good solution rather than _yes you can_ or _no you can't_

Comment: Hi mike, see my updated answer based on your added fiddle example, comment below it if you need further help.

Comment: Well, this is nice, but I get the markup from asp.net, so I wouldn't change it.

Comment: Then you will need to use javascript as I mention in the answer.

Comment: Agree, if I don't change the controls for the desired markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:enabled` CSS pseudo-class represents any enabled element. It's commonly being used on form elements I believe. Unless you declared `:disabled` to the element, otherwise `:enabled` is the default state.

Also most of the form elements don't allow to have any pseudo elements such as `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`... but some are allowed, such as `<button>`.

```css
button:enabled:after {
  content: "*"
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
<button enabled>Button</button>
<button disabled>Button</button>
```

For elements that don't have pseudo elements, you can use sibling selector `+` or `~` with a span tag to achieve the same results.

```css
input[type="radio"]:enabled + span:after {
  content: "*"
}
```

```html
<input name="test" type="radio"> 1 <span></span>
<input name="test" type="radio" enabled> 2 <span></span>
<input name="test" type="radio" disabled> 3 <span></span>
```

Examples based on your code, also made the radio in the center of the circle.

- [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLvvmvL2/) - plain CSS with modified markup structure.
- [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j71a6xkh/) - with jQuery and original markup structure.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. You cannot add `:before` or `:after` pseudo on form elements. Basically they render inside container elements.

The best you can do is have an empty element besides your input, say a `span` and use a selector like

```
input[type=text]:enabled + span:after {
  /* Props goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:after` can work only with elements that have closing tags + It doesn't work with tag `<select>`.
And as `:enabled` is usually used with forms, it will not work together.

If you work with form It's easier to wrap its elements in `<div>` and then just add `:after` to it.

You may also share your code for better understanding of a problem.